# No events when drag target is removed from the scenegraph while dragging

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

JavaFX scene has an object of class inherited from the Region. This object has a handler of MOUSE_DRAGGED event. When this handler is called, all object's child nodes are removed and new child nodes are added. The problem is when all children are removed from my object, it doesn't receive any events anymore, because target of MOUSE_DRAGGED event is removed child node. How to solve it?

I cannot use setMouseTransparent method, because some elements inside my object have mouse event handlers.

Comment: I don't got the problem. You have a region with some children shown. These children are draggable... what is the expected behaviour? Shall the region be notifed if chldren are dragged away?

Comment: @Jens-PeterHaack I don't want to drag the children. I need to change nodes in the region, when the user is holding the left mouse button down or moving the mouse over the region while holding the left mouse button down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, perhaps I got the question:

A region has many children. If the user left-clicks and dragges on these children, they will be modified or even removed. As the Mouse-Drag event is 'locked' to the first child where the drag started, no other child will receive further events if the mouse is dragged over some of the other children.

You might benefit from the fact, that the MouseDrag event is passed to the parent region after removing the child. So it is possible to register an onMouseDragged handler on th eparent regon receiving that event. Now the handler is able to 'pick' any childs below mouse for further actions using event.getPickEvent():

```
void mouseDragPop(Pane region) {
    region.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        Node node = e.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
        if (node instanceof Circle) {
            region.getChildren().remove(node);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        final int n = i;
        Circle circle = new Circle(20);
        circle.setTranslateX(0);
        circle.setTranslateY(0);
        circle.setFill(Color.rgb(180,  200,  170));
        circle.setLayoutX(System.nanoTime()/1000 % 200);
        circle.setLayoutY(System.nanoTime()/3000 % 100);
        region.getChildren().add(circle);

        circle.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            region.getChildren().remove(circle);
            e.consume();
        });
    }
}
```

Now you are able to click and 'pop' all circle on your mouse-drag way...
[image]

Comment: also, I need the same behavior when a user press the mouse (MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED).

Comment: So do the same, pass the event up and handle at region. Use getPickEvent() to refocus on the children below the mouse and perform your operation... you might also pass the 'pick event' to the event handler of the picked child node.

Comment: _You might benefit from the fact, that the MouseDrag event is passed to the parent region after removing the child._ I use javafx 2.2. It is not true for this version of javafx. But I understood your idea and I can do something similar.